# WPF ModernUI in parent Window

Tags: c#, wpf, parent

I develop a language learning project. i use modern UI and in want fix my page screen in 1024*768. i want to have parent window like mdi parent in background and other modern ui window load inside it. how can i implement this like Tell me more or rosseta stone ?
i already use http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/ and got error because i have window not user control.
[image of Sample](http://upload7.ir/images/46466351629698390059.png)

Answer (score 0):

Call the Show() method, and before that set top and left for the top left corner of your modernUI window. You can do it like this:

```
ModernUIWindow MUW = new ModernUIWindow();
Canvas.SetTop(MUW, 100);
Canvas.SetLeft(MUW,100);
```

All of this code should be in the constructor of the MainWindow. This way, your moderUI window will be shown on the top of your MainWindow.

Comment: Yes i know. but my main window inherits ModernUI window and i can't set this to content of other window or grid.

Comment: As I know, you just cannot put a window inside a window. A window cannot be the chile of a Canvas, Grid or a StackPanel. The solution I gave will make it look like you have a window inside a window. You can modify your code so that if the MainWindow is moved - so will the ModerUI window.

Comment: I can't understand what can i do to implement this?

Comment: You simply can't - no window inside a window allowed in .Net.

Comment: What the other way? how can i implement this in another way?

Comment: What the other way? how can i implement this in another way?

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice solution for your problem
 [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22927/Multiple-Window-Interface-for-WPF).
Another solution is to draw label or buttons with images of X for closing the window and _ to minimize the window. This case your inner window will not be a real window, but a UI display that resembles a window.